# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytube'

Tags: python, cmd, pip, pytube

quiero utilizar la libreria pytube para poder descargar videos en youtube, pero me marca el error del titulo el cual nose como poder resolver.
-el modulo ya esta instalado correctamente y me da la version de la libreria como tal

-ya cheque igual las variables de entorno pero aun asi sigue marcandome error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui se puede ver todas las librerias que tengo instaladas hasta ahora

no entiendo porque no me lee la libreria,el editor decodigo no me marca ningun error, la libreria tampoco me notifica si esta intalada o no,que de hecho me aparece como modulo,lo cual significa que al menos vscode si reconocio esa libreria

aniado el como estoy implementando la libreria
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el mensaje que se visualiza en la consola cada que quiero correr el codigo:
[image]

aqui esta la version instalada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si alguien ha tenido algun problema similar,por favor seria de mucha ayuda que compartan sus conocimientos y experiencias

*por si surge la duda,otras librerias que tambien tengo instaladas como numpy si que me las lee,por lo que quiero pensar que las variables de entorno estan bien configuradas por tal motivo, aunque reconozco que podria estar equivocado :c

Comment: Que error te sale sii pones `pip install pytube`??

Comment: @AlfaRojo por qué supones que saldrá error?? Lo más probable es que salga un `success`

Comment: @AlfaRojo  me aparece el siguiente mensaje,ya esta instalado: Requirement already satisfied: pytube in c:\users\sergi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (11.0.1).

Comment: Tienes 2 o más versiones de Python instaladas en tu compu? Puede que hayas instalado la libreria en una version de Python y ejecutado el script con otra. Por ejemplo, instalaste pytube en python2.7 y ejecutaste el script con python 3.2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

para chequear si un modulo esta instalado debes abrir la consola

```
python [enter]
import pytube [enter]
```

si no te da un error es que esta instalado en el sistema.

Comment: ,me he dado cuenta de mi error al no comprobar si numpy esta o no instalado, comprobe que numpy tampoco fue reconocido,lo que tuve que hacer es desinstalar la version python que descargue desde la tienda de microsoft y instalarla desde internet,afortunadamente con la reconfiguracion de la nueva instalacion pude por fin comprobar que el error fue debido a dos versiones python 3.9 que tenia,ya puedo leer pytube por fin :D